# Clean hair from vacuum brush

Tags: cleaning, home, hair, appliances

I own a roomba and while its cool and saves time and everything, cleaning the counter rotating brushes inside it is bothersome. I have long hair.

I usually open the roomba and remove the brushes, then sit at my desk, the dustbin between my legs and try to grab some hair from it and pull it out.

I've tried applying a paperclip as hook but it didn't help. I tried a nail scissor but its to large to fit inside the smaller parts.

[image: Roomba brushes]

Especially the small gaps are difficult (in the above image the upper brush has one very small gap on the right side. This part is full of my hair.

Note: It takes me about 15 - 20 minutes to clean both brushes. That is okay, but I would prefer it to take about 1 - 5 minutes.

Comment: A razor blade could help but you'd have to be careful of damaging the brush...

Comment: Roombas usually come with two specific tool: a special (knife)[https://www.amazon.com/Roomba-Replacement-Bristle-Beater-Cleaning/dp/B00BY3VPPQ/ref=pd_bxgy_201_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00BY3VPPQ&pd_rd_r=W28GYNWTJY22VNBWNJG4&pd_rd_w=eWRZr&pd_rd_wg=dpaLS&psc=1&refRID=W28GYNWTJY22VNBWNJG4] for cutting the hair, and a ("tube")[https://www.amazon.com/iRobot-80901-Brush-Cleaning-Roomba/dp/B0013FFZ8I] to remove the hair. Didn't you get them too?

Comment: @Neinstein No, I did not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly I usually just use a razor blade for this sort of thing, but if you're concerned about safety and/or damaging the agitators you may want to try a [Seam Ripper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_ripper)

[image]

It is a tool that is designed for carefully splitting seams and removing thread/stitching when sewing.

It works well for removing hair and carpet fibers from vacuums because it allows you to "hook" the fibers/hair and cut them loose in a single motion without dragging a sharp edge on the agitator. In case it isn't obvious in the image, the cutting edge is located on the curve between the two points.

Comment: I can confirm this works well.

Comment: I tried it today, works like a charm. I used the seam splitter of my victorinox and was done in like 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the seam splitter (apaul) try using an old dinner fork to ease out the hair and fluff from the brush bristles using a combing action.
This brings everything out to the end of the bristles and makes it easy to pinch out, leaving a relatively clean brush.

Answer (score -2):

We've got German Shepherd's (long hair) and our vacuum's are getting continually clogged up. We used to use scissors but have recently tried a [RollaReleasa](https://www.rollareleasa.com/) which is great at picking and cutting.

Comment: Hi George O, Welcome to Lifehacks.SE. We hope you enjoy your time here. Please visit the Help Centre (? menu icon) above for information about how better to use this site.