# How to get hair out of a brush

Tags: cleaning, home, hair

I have a hair brush that works well, but tends to get a lot of hair stuck in it. I need an effective way to clean all of this hair out.

I've tried:

- Pulling  it out - this takes long and is laborious
- Washing it out with water - this does nothing, it even makes the problem worse

Are there any quick effective ways to get all of the hair out of a brush?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this answer may work for you: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2468/32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Anithamallya’s blog](https://anithamallya.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/how-to-clean-hair-brushes/) and [madefrompinterest](http://www.madefrompinterest.net/clean-brush-minutes/) article, few interesting comments and adapted instructions, you should follow these steps:

1. You need toothpicks, scissors anything small and flat that can get through the bristles to the base of the comb to get all the hair out.
2. Taking some scissors, cut the hair in the brush lengthwise down every 2nd or 3rd row making sure you are  cutting in between the bristles.
3. Taking the tip of the scissors, slide the scissors lengthwise underneath the hair and lift.  The hair should lift right up.  Continue until  all the hair has been removed.
4. Optionally use the hose attachment on the vacuum cleaner and I vacuum the rest of the hair off the brush.
5. When most of the bulky hair has been removed, set your brush in a sink that has some warm water mixed with a small amount of shampoo or dishwashing liquid.

   Alternatively  use white vinegar along with shampoo and baking soda. Wet brush, sprinkle with baking soda, and pour about 1/4 teaspoon, 1 teaspoon of white vinegar over baking soda. Leave it for 15 minutes.

   Or if you don't have white vinegar, put baking soda or ammonia in a tall glass, add a brush and combs, then add boiling water and let it sit.
6. Taking a spare toothbrush, scrub/brush vigorously up and down each row of your hair brush and also all around the top.
7. Set on paper towel to dry.

Comment: Depending in your brush, kenorb's answer without cutting the hair (ie skip step 2) also works well, and makes the removed hair easier to dispose of.

Answer (score 6):

Kenorb's answer seems very thorough but, if you're OK with the results not being *perfect*, you can use my method: Scrape it out with a fork. The tines get between the brush bristles easily and, by grabbing it in 3 or 4 places at once, it's much more likely that you can pull out the entire hair instead of breaking it or slipping loose. I strongly recommend that you wash the fork before eating with it.

Source: I've done this and it totally works, even on dog brushes.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have a comb, right?

Hold the brush in one hand and the comb in the other. Put the comb at the end of the brush that is furthest from you and wiggle it right down to the ends of the bristles where they meet the back of the brush. Now pull the comb towards you (along the length of the brush) gathering the mat of hair out of the bristles as you go. Eventually the comb pops out of the bristles at the end closest to you, with the hair all in front of it. Pull the hair off the comb with your fingers and throw it away.

Takes less time to do than to read.

Answer (score 0):

Put a piece of paper in the bottom of the brush, make sure the bristles can go through, or instead of paper( use something that can get wet and stay dry, if you brush your hair wet) after this step brush your hair normal and they once you are ready to pull off the hair rip the paper( or whatever you used) off and your brush should be cleared, then reapply.